# What is the use of Facebook Android Key hash for sample apps?

Tags: android, facebook, hash, facebook-android-sdk

I wanted to understand the use of Facebook Android Key hash for sample apps ?
What is the relevance of setting the hash ? The thing that is confusing me is that I was able to run the sample apps without setting up the hash in developer settings also.

Some clarification would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

The sample apps key hash allows you to build the sample apps that ship with the SDK on your machine, using your debug key, and still do things like login and share using the native dialogs. If you didn't set that, then you won't be able to do things like SSO login using the Facebook app.

Comment: It is still not clear. I didn't had the hash code configured in my developer settings on FB but still I was able to use the sample apps. It successfully navigated to facebook and I was able to share things also . So where does hash code fit-in.

Comment: I tried with sample.hellofacebook which has a login button on the top , I clicked the login and I was able to login via facebook into the app and I was able to share post as well !

Comment: Do you have the Facebook app installed, or was it using the web dialog?

Comment: I have the app installed .

Comment: I don't see anything lile this .. P.S : I am doing it on a actual device and not an emulator.